# Why access zsmalloc should be in atomic contex

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel, atomic, zlib

when we call zs_map_object, the return value is per-CPU object? why can't we allow mapping in interrupt context?

Comment: I don't see a reason either, have you tried asking in linux-mm mailing list? I would ask there first, and Cc Minchan Kim specifically.

Answer (score 0):

It's easy to see if you check the code.

It seems you are allowed to have at most one mapping at a time.

Now let's take a look:

```
area = &get_cpu_var(zs_map_area);
area->vm_mm = mm;
if (off + class->size <= PAGE_SIZE) {
        /* this object is contained entirely within a page */
        area->vm_addr = kmap_atomic(page);
        ret = area->vm_addr + off;
        goto out;
}

/* this object spans two pages */
pages[0] = page;
pages[1] = get_next_page(page);
```

And there you go - imagine what happens if an interrupt fires *after* the mapping starts getting set up, e.g. after area->vm_mm = mm line. Whatever work was done will be overwritten by the code running from the handler, but there is nothing to recover it after the handler returns, thus giving a bug.